# Do I need to call next() after res.send()?

Tags: express

If I called `res.send()`, but didn't call `next()`:

1. Any middleware after this middleware won't be executed.
2. If this middleware is not the last middleware, then the request will "hang" forever, and will not be garbage collected, because It is still waiting for the `next()` to be called.

The above is my attempt to argue that I should always call `next()`, is it true?

Comment: if you like the answer please accept it thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You *don't need to call* `next()` to finish sending the response. `res.send()` or `res.json()` should end all writing to the response stream and send the response.

However, *you absolutely can call* `next()` if you want to do further processing after the response is sent, just make sure you don't write to the response stream after you call `res.send()`.

Comment: But is express writing something by default? because I have no additional middlewares and if I call it I get an error.

Comment: by default, express has middleware that will send a 404 error if no middleware handled the request. if you put in middleware and dont call next() then you wont get a 404.

Comment: @AlexanderMills, correcting as your comment is slightly misleading (a subordinate got confused). At least in Express 4.x a 404 handler is not a middleware, and more of a simple baked-in logic (i.e. if none of the middleware/handlers handled the request then craft a default 404 reply).

Answer (score 10):

**Simply**

1. All the middlewares use same `request and response` objects, so if you send the `response` via any middleware all next middlewares will be skipped
2. You can still execute further operations by calling `next();` but you can't do `res.send()` or `res.json()` further