# Using axios to POST within my ExpressJS app is giving me "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error

Tags: node.js, express, http, axios

I have a simple Express app with a couple of routes. One route in particular is a POST route. In this POST route I'm trying to make a POST to a third-party API and use the data from this third-party API response in my actual POST response. The app looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();

...

app.post(
  '/api/links',
  (req, res, next)=> {
    const data = req.body;

    axios.post('https://third.party.api.com/api/v1', data, headers)
      .then(data => res.json(data.data))
      .catch(err => res.send(err));
    next();
  }
)
```

The GET requests I've defined works, but the POST does not. I'm using axios to make a POST here to a third-party API in the middle of the `/api/links` POST. I want my endpoint to return data from this third-party API when there's a success, which is why I have the `res.json(data.data)`. I'm using `res.json` without issues in my GET routes, but when I use it in my POST route I get the error `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` from the `res.json()` line. I've tried stripping out axios and using plain `https` instead, but I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the callbacks, next will be called before you return a response (and so subsequent handlers will have already sent the response before you return from the post call).  This is why get an ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error.

So instead of:

```
axios.post('https://third.party.api.com/api/v1', data, headers)
  .then(data => res.json(data.data))
  .catch(err => res.send(err));
next();
```

This:

```
axios.post('https://third.party.api.com/api/v1', data, headers)
  .then(data => res.json(data.data))
  .then(_=>     next())
  .catch(err => res.send(err));
```

You might want to look at your get handler and see what you actually do there.

If you don't have any post-processing middleware installed you shouldn't call next at all. But I'm  assume you do. Check out this thread for more information: [Do I need to call next() after res.send()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701123/do-i-need-to-call-next-after-res-send)

The cause of your problem remains having that next() called before the promise resolves.

Comment: `next` doesn't often (ever?) need to be called when the response is sent... that tends to invoke a 404 handler which will also generate the headers error.

Comment: This is not correct.  You never want to call `next()` here.

Comment: I dunno, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701123/do-i-need-to-call-next-after-res-send.  You definitely might have middle ware you want to run after your handler.  You just can't write to the response stream again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to `next()`.  That continues routing and sends some other response from some other handler.  When you are sending a response in your own processing, you want to end the routing and you do that by NOT calling `next()`.