# Why don't I get the expected error of "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." in this scenario for Express? What is happening & is this ok?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following NodeJS code, it simply spins up the express server, and the route calls next, but has a setTimeout in it that calls next again.

In this case, **I was expecting to get the common error of** `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` but to my surprise, I don't get any kind of error? What is happening here, I tried reading the docs for the behavior of the Express next() method (that calls the next middleware) but I don't see anything that talks about this certain scenario really.

Also, will doing this have any repercussions? (Memory leaks, bugs, etc.?)

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/users', (req, res, next) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        res.data = {
            userId: 2,
            name: "You will never see me"
        };
        // call next without foul!
        return next();
    }, 1000);
    res.data = {
        userId: 1,
        name: 'test'
    };
    return next();
});

// middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!res.headersSent && req.route) {
        res.status(res.statusCode);
        return res.json({data: res.data, success: true});
    }
    return next();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: You're not supposed to call `next()` more than once for the same request. Indeed this doesn't seem to be clearly documented, but it makes sense; you can handle a request only once.

Comment: @Thomas, I have seen else where (granted, in stackoverflow), that it's "ok" to call next() as long as you don't call res.send() or res.json()

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51531541/5339639

So, I wonder if doing what I am doing is ok/won't have any side effects.